# Set iOS dynamic quick action icon from url

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickaction

I'm working but on iOS dynamic quick actions, and I want to use image from url, to be set as the quick action icon.

Is it possible? I didn't find an answer for that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible using public API.

`UIApplicationShortcutIcon` only allows creating icons from contacts, images found in the bundle or predefined system icons.

If you are willing to use private API (you shouldn't), there exist two methods which allow this:

```
+ (id)iconWithCustomImage:(id)arg1 isTemplate:(_Bool)arg2;
+ (id)iconWithCustomImage:(id)arg1;
```

It still wouldn't be a URL. You'd need to create a `UIImage` instance and call these methods with that image.

Comment: since this is the approved answer, I will stress on that **you shouldn't**: please bear in mind that using private APIs will likely have your app rejected if you submit it to the App Store. And if it doesn't get rejected on the first release, it might be at any time in the future.

Comment: I agree with @il3v. While it is possible to hide private API use, it is still not recommended as it can cause crashes or otherwise unexpected behavior in future iOS versions.